# Etymology of the idiom "by and large"

Tags: etymology, idioms

The idiomatic phrase *[by and large](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/by+and+large)* means

> largely; generally; mostly

The two earliest usages listed in Google's [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=by%20and%20large&year_start=1800&year_end=1900&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,by%20and%20large;,c0), from 1812 and 1837, appear to use it in its current form and meaning.

What is the origin of this phrase?

Comment: Perhaps the earliest known use of ['by and large'](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/by-and-large.html) in print is from 1669. [Here](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-bya1.htm) is another link.

Comment: I just know "Buy n Large" :D

Comment: This is one of many phrases of nautical origin that people use idiomatically with no understanding of the original meaning. "Give some leeway" is similarly common; "leeway" is the result of unavoidable sideways deviation of a ship from its intended course, which must be considered when steering towards an upwind mark.

Comment: "Taken aback" is another -- idiomatically meaning to be surprised by an unexpected negative event. A sailcraft is "taken aback" when - typically due to sudden wind shift or poor handling while turning towards the wind - it is being blown backwards with the wind on the wrong side of the sails. This is particularly dangerous when the ship is square-rigged.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[by and large](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/by-and-large.html): it appears to have a nautical origin:

> To get a sense of the original meaning of the phrase  we need to understand the nautical terms 'by' and 'large'.
>
> *'Large'* is easier, so we'll start there. When the wind is blowing from some compass point behind a ship's direction of travel then it is said to be 'large'*. Sailors have used this term for centuries; for example, this piece from Richard Hakluyt's The Principall Navigations, Voiages, and Discoveries of the English Nation, 1591:
>   "When the wind came larger we waied anchor and set saile."
>   When the wind is in that favourable 'large' direction the largest square sails may be set and the ship is able to travel in whatever downwind direction the captain sees fit.
>
> *'By'* is a rather more difficult concept for landlubbers like me. *In simplified terms it means '*in the general direction of'. Sailors would say that to be 'by the wind' is to face into the wind or within six compass points of it.
>
> The earliest known reference to 'by and large' in print is from Samuel Sturmy, in The Mariners Magazine, 1669.

Comment: I wonder if this usage of 'large' could have any relation to the French expression *au large de*, which means 'off the coast of'.

Comment: @DavidConrad: Littré and the TLF dictionary do not list any sense that would support this. 'Large' means essentially 'wide' or 'broad' in French, 'au large' could be transposed as "wide of the shore".

Comment: @Joce The TLF does have "*Au large* (*de* + subst.). Au delà (de), à distance (de)" and gives an example from Verne with "*au large du littoral*", but that just means "beyond" or "at a distance from", not "offshore". But I have seen it used that way, and wordreference.com [translates it that way](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/au%20large%20de) and has discussions of native speakers [using it in that sense](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=2738014).

Comment: But that may suggest it's a more recent development, and unlikely to be the source of the English expression.

Comment: It's difficult to specify PoS for _large_ in Hakluyt's 'the wind came larger': adverb or predicative adjective. 'By' seems to be an adverb (it's certainly an adverbial usage here, but some would claim it's a prime example of an intransitive preposition). 'And' usually only coordinates equivalents (PoS's, clauses ...).

Comment: Thank you! I've always thought that to really understand English, one needs to know about ships.

Comment: This does not seem to me to accord precisely with the way the phrase is used. As the OP points out it means "largely", "generally", "mostly". For me an exact synonym would be "on the whole". However the nautical reference would suggest it meant "in all circumstances" - which is not the case.

Answer (score 24):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_nautical_terms#B) states:

> *By* means into the wind, while *large* means with the wind. "By and large" is used to indicate all possible situations "*the ship handles well both by and large*".

Answer (score 0):

Sailing term yes. I am not only sailor but a certified (American Sailing Association or ASA) sailing instructor. These are two words with two different meanings
1. Sailing "BY" the wind is directional. It means "Into the wind" (typically 90 to 45 degrees off the eye of the wind (no one can sail directly into the wind).
2. Sailing "Large" is All (or most) of the sails are deployed ("unfurled" or raised).

Two possible meanings:
1. Sailing into the wind with all the sails fully deployed. But... some sails only work downwind. But if not so equipped, it would be for very light wind. Basically making the most of what you've got. Not really how we hear "By & Large" used.
2. On a long journey, one typically will sail both by the wind and downwind. Sailing downwind is much easier than sailing upwind. Downwind the sails are set with little adjustment and the waves are pushing you along and typically, all the sails can be used. Conversely, upwind is pounding against the oncoming waves and takes constant crew adjustment by the sail trimmers and the helmsman. It is a much rougher ride of all on board. So if asked (in 1800), "How was your trip to England and back?" You could say, "By and Large" it was *** (what every). It is a mix of the rough going with the easy going, more or less in other words.